# How to use WebAction.Request in Power Query M?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to build a HTTP Post from scratch without any body, I'm trying to use WebAction.Request though there's little or no documentation on how to use it.

From the documentation method returns an action, though nowhere I can find how to execute an action.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've always used Web.Contents() even for POST requests. Are you sure you need to use WebAction.Request?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but yes... For multiple reasons:

1) It should be a POST (in WebAction.Request only possible with content)

2) I want to use with Anonymous credentials (only when there's no content)


3) It should have no content (to use anonymous credentials)

:)

Comment: I'm even more confused now lol.
Hopefully someone helps you.
What I know is that you can setup the Content parameter in Web.Contents() and send requests with anonymous credentials as well.